# Swift startIndex from string

Tags: swift

I'm having a weird bug in my code. I'm building an iOS app in Swift.
The code contains the following function:

```
func generateAttrString(path: String?) {
    do {
        let content = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let array = content.componentsSeparatedByString("\n¶")
        let attrStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        attrStyle.lineSpacing = 8
        attrStyle.paragraphSpacing = 12

        for element in array {
            var string = element
            var attributes = [
                NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: attrStyle,
                NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "MyriadPro-Light", size: 17.0)!
            ]

            var attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes: attributes)
            if string[string.startIndex] == "•" {
                string.removeAtIndex(string.startIndex)
                attributes[NSFontAttributeName] = UIFont(name: "MyriadPro-Regular", size: 17.0)!

                let newAttrStyle = attrStyle.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
                newAttrStyle.paragraphSpacing = 3
                newAttrStyle.lineSpacing = 0
                attributes[NSParagraphStyleAttributeName] = newAttrStyle

                attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes: attributes)
            }


            contentArray.append((false, attrString))
        }

    } catch _ {
    }
}
```

at the specific part of:

```
if string[string.startIndex] == "•" {
```

it is giving me an error, I tried adding a breakpoint before, and tried printing "string", this returned me the string. After that I tried string[string.startIndex] == "•", it returned true. But now if I run the code and try opening the page where this code runs I get the following error:

**fatal error: Can't form a Character from an empty String**

Any idea on how to solve this? The string don't seems to be empty...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an empty string you'll see that error. If you test first to make sure the string isn't empty you should be okay.

```
if !string.isEmpty && string[string.startIndex] == "•"  {
```